# OLE2.H file hitting _MAC sections, but not if I add a tab

Tags: c++, makefile

I came across something interesting today when trying to build one of our C++ modules. The module itself hasn't been built for over 3 years, and when I attempted the build I got a make error:

```
Make Error: c:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\VC98\INCLUDE\ole2.h: Cannot find file 'macname1.h'
```

I looked around the internet for a fix, but haven't found anything else useful as yet, so i turned to the `OLE2.H` file instead. When I look in there, there is a large `#ifndef _MAC` and a corresponding `#else` which has my missing include file.

From this I can presume that something is setting the `_MAC` variable before this file is included, so I amend the file and added  `undef _MAC` just before the first `#ifndef`.  I am surprised to say however that this didn't do a thing.

Eventually I happened to add some tabs to the file so I could work out the if/else pairs. BOOM... If I take the entire `#ifndef` block and add a tab at the start of the line, the `_MAC` is correctly being picked up. So much so, I can even remove the additional `#undef` that I added, and it still works.

If I move the block back to column 1, I get the make error. If I add a tab again, it works.

**EDIT:** I only need to tab the main include that is giving me problems:

```
#include "macname1.h"
```

vs

```
    #include "macname1.h"
```

Has anyone ever experienced this before?  I don't really want to be editing core Windows include files to get one module to build.

Thanks

Comment: I'd try running your file through the preprocessor with the `/P` option to get the preprocessor output into a file and look to see if there's any clue there about what's going on. Also maybe look at some suspect files with a hex editor to see if there's a funky control character or something that might be confusing things (I'd also look at the headers that are 'above' `ole2.h` in the tree of files that result in `ole2.h` being included).

Comment: Also, you might want to compare the files in `VC98\Include` on your machine with the ones on the installation CD to see if there are any signs of corruption - you might need a reinstall.  Keep in mind that there might be differences that are due to service packs or other normal activity. You should look for corruption or diffs that don't make sense.